# Wrap Python type hints for customized `Annotated` types with `Union`

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, typing, subtyping

Okay, so the idea is that in Pydantic, one can do something like this:

```py
from typing import Literal
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field


class A(BaseModel):
    disc: Literal["a"]
    other: str = "asdf"

class B(BaseModel):
    disc: Literal["b"]
    other: int = 23


class Thing(BaseModel):
    foo: Annotated[Union[A, B], Field(discriminator="disc")]
```

And I am creating a base model that will always contain the same discriminator.

Basically I'd like to subclass `Thing` and not worry about the

```py
Annotated[..., Field(discriminator="disc")]
```

part at all.

Basically, I wanted something like:

```py
CustomUnion[A,B,...]
```

that would be equivalent to:

```py
Annotated[Union[A, B,...], Field(discriminator="disc")]
```

I think I can go as far as this:

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Union
from pydantic import BaseModel


BaseModelT = TypeVar("BaseModelT", bound=BaseModel)
Disc = Annotated[BaseModelT, Field(discriminator="disc")]

Disc[Union[A, B, ...]]
```

But I'd like to go flatter, enforcing also at least two parameters like `Union` does.

Comment: PEP646 (variadic generics) should be helpful ([very similar example in docs](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/#aliases)), but it is not supported by `mypy` yet.